# SortedSet - sort and remove duplicates

Tags: java, set, equals, comparator, sortedset

I have a class with multiple attributes:

```
class Person {
   String firstName;
   String lastName;
   String country;
   String hometown;
}
```

What I would like is to remove all duplicates(based on firstName and lastName) and sort the set by country and hometown.

I tried implementing equals() and hashCode() in class Person and then write a Comparator to construct the SortedSet with but the Set uses the Comparator for equality as well. Is there any way I can achieve this?

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Person other = (Person) obj;
    if (firstName == null) {
        if (other.firstName != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!firstName.equals(firstName.type))
        return false;
    if (lastName == null) {
        if (other.lastName != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!lastName.equals(other.lastName))
        return false;
    return true;
}

Set<Person> uniquePersonList = new TreeSet<>(
        Comparator.comparing(Person::getCountry)
                        .thenComparing(Person::getHometown));
```

Comment: You could do this in two passes: one to de-dup, one to sort. Once you use a comparator, that comparator takes over.

Comment: If the same person (same name) comes twice with different home towns, do you need to control which of the two you keep? To ask the other way around, is it OK to just keep any one of them?

Comment: I agree with @DavidEhrmann: You probably need to keep two sets, one unsorted for duplicate detection (like `HashSet`), and one sorted for the order. Whenever you have a new `Person` object, check if it is in the unsorted set, and only if it isn’t, add it to both sets.

Comment: Are you wanting that comparator? Will it allow you to have more than one person in the same town? (or are they going to be very small towns? :-) )

Comment: In my understanding of object-orientation (and understandings differ, so you need not agree) you should avoid having two `Person` objects representing the same person. So when a person moves to another town, an approach I’d applaud would be to take the person out of the sorted set, change the hometown and country and reinsert the person into the set (so it gets its correct position in the sort order).